# MVC Send Script in View to Other Servers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a .NET MVC application on one server and my main website on another. There are some pages on the website that do an ajax call to the MVC and get a view to display. I've always had these two projects on the same server, but now that I have split them up I have a problem.

For instance, I want to send a script file from the server with the MVC as part of the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SnazzyPlugin.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This worked fine, because everything was on the same server. Now, it tries to find the script on the machine that has the website, and I get a 404, because it's looking on localhost (for now) for the snazzyPlugin.js, but it's really on the server. How can I include the snazzyPlugin.js as part of the view that actually gets returned?

Comment: Do you need to send the entire script? What if you set your `src` to reference your page, wouldn't it work?